# idmap range on Ubuntu 20.04 (sssd) does not match CentOS 7 winbind idmaps (kinda)

Tags: active-directory, authentication, user-management, sssd, ubuntu-20.04

My Active Directory maps in Ubuntu systems are very long compared to my CentOS IDs  The last 4 digits match but Ubunutu seems to be adding a lot more to the beginning.

In CentOS winbind/samba I used a range to get the IDs I needed:

```
    idmap config * : range = 10000-20000
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    idmap config MYDOMAIN : default = yes
    idmap config MYDOMAIN : range = 10000-24999999
    idmap config MYDOMAIN : backend = rid
```

Which would produce an ID like 1**1695** on Centos

Ubuntu 20.04 produces guid/uid of  155880**1695**, which adds 155880 and removed the leading 1 from 11695.

How can I format Ubuntu's sssd config to give me what I need. All my files and folders are tagged with the Centos IDs and CentOS does not recognize these longer ones?

I hope I explained this ok.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to read up on [SSSD's ID Mapping](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/sssd-ad.5.html#id%20mapping).  To duplicate the `rid` generated ids then you will need to set a *default domain* in SSSD and configure the id ranges to match.

I believe these SSSD settings will match your samba config

```
ldap_id_mapping = true
ldap_schema = ad
ldap_idmap_default_domain_sid = S-1-5-21-REDACTED
ldap_idmap_range_min = 10000
ldap_idmap_range_max = 24999999
```

You will need to get your Active Directory SID for the `ldap_idmap_default_domain_sid` value.  You might be able to get this from the CentOS box with the command `net getdomainsid`.  I have *not* gotten the related `ldap_idmap_default_domain` setting to work.

If you are setting up Samba on the Ubuntu server then you can unify the ids by using the `idmap_sss` backend for Winbind.

When changing id mapping settings in SSSD it is best to completely clear the local cache to see what effect the changes had.

```
systemctl stop sssd
rm /var/lib/sss/{db,mc}/*
sss_cache -E
# optionally clear debug logs
truncate -s 0 /var/log/sssd/*.log
systemctl start sssd
```

Comment: Wow! That worked! All my best. Cheers and Thanks so much.